# D3 - Create Dynamic "Border" Rectangle around SVG group

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have an SVG group with a rect inside of it, and would like the rect to act as a border for the group...

```
<g>
  <rect></rect>
</g>
```

but the group is dynamic and its content changes. I am attempting to resize the rect in my update function as such

```
.attr("x", function(d) { return this.parentNode.getBBox().x })
.attr("y", function(d) { return this.parentNode.getBBox().y })
.attr("width", function(d) { return this.parentNode.getBBox().width })
.attr("height", function(d) { return this.parentNode.getBBox().height })
```

But what seems to happen is that it expands relatively fine, but then cannot shrink properly since the group's bounding box width is now the same as the expanded rect's width (the rect's width is the group's width, but the group's width is now the rect's width).

Is there any way to get a rectangle inside an SVG group to properly resize and act as a border?

Comment: Why do you need the `rect` to be a child of the `g` element?

Comment: @Duopixel That made things more organized (as you would expect a border to be inside its group, not outside), but you're right, I didn't need it to be a child! If you add this as answer I'll accept it because this obvious solution fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest, cross-browser compatible way is to implement a border is to use a `rect` exactly as I did, but place it outside of the group, as mentioned by @Duopixel in his comment. As it is still positioned by the bounding box, it will have the correct width, height, x, and y.

```html
<rect></rect>
<g></g>
```

Answer (score 8):

There's more than one way to solve this.

- Use the `outline` property (**2014-08-05 status:** works in Chrome and Opera)

  ```
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500px" height="500px">
    <g style="outline: thick solid black; outline-offset: 10px;">
      <circle cx="50" cy="60" r="20" fill="yellow"/>
      <rect x="80" y="80" width="200" height="100" fill="blue"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
  ```

  See [live example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/css/outline-border.svg).
- Use a `filter` to generate the border (**2014-08-05 status:** works in Firefox, but Chrome/Opera has a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=400653) on feMorphology, but it should be possible to work around that by using other filter primitives).

  ```
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <defs>
      <filter id="border" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
        <feFlood flood-color="black" result="outer"/>
        <feMorphology operator="erode" radius="2" in="outer" result="inner"/>
        <feComposite in="inner" in2="outer" operator="xor"/>
        <feComposite in2="SourceGraphic"/>
      </filter>
    </defs>
    <g filter="url(#border)">
      <circle cx="50" cy="60" r="20" fill="yellow"/>
      <rect x="80" y="80" width="200" height="100" fill="blue"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
  ```

  See [live example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/filters/border.svg).

Both of the above will automatically update to whatever size the group has, without the need for DOM modifications.

Comment: Why have I never heard of the `outline` property? Every post I've seen on SO for SVG borders involves `rect` but this is far easier! I can't seem to get it run on IE9 though, even though MDN says it should work with IE8+ :\

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can find the new bounding box by selecting all child elements of the group that are not the bounding rect itself, and then calculating the overall bounding box based on the individual bounding boxes of the children.

Lets say your bounding rect had a class of `bounding-rect`, you could do the following:

```
function updateRect() {
  // SELECT ALL CHILD NODES EXCEPT THE BOUNDING RECT
  var allChildNodes = theGroup.selectAll(':not(.bounding-rect)')[0]

  // `x` AND `y` ARE SIMPLY THE MIN VALUES OF ALL CHILD BBOXES
  var x = d3.min(allChildNodes, function(d) {return d.getBBox().x;}),
      y = d3.min(allChildNodes, function(d) {return d.getBBox().y;}),

      // WIDTH AND HEIGHT REQUIRE A BIT OF CALCULATION
      width = d3.max(allChildNodes, function(d) {
        var bb = d.getBBox();
        return (bb.x + bb.width) - x;
      }),

      height = d3.max(allChildNodes, function(d) {
        var bb = d.getBBox();
        return (bb.y + bb.height) - y;
      });

  // UPDATE THE ATTRS FOR THE RECT
  svg.select('.bounding-rect')
     .attr('x', x)
     .attr('y', y)
     .attr('width', width)
     .attr('height', height);
}
```

This would set the x and y values of the overall bounding box to be the minimum x and y values in the childrens' bounding boxes. Then the overall width is calculated by finding the maximum right boundary `bb.x + bb.width` and subtracting the overall box's x. The overall height is then calculated in the same way as the width.

[**HERE**](http://jsbin.com/pebix/1/edit?js,output) is an example of this.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer! Unfortunately, even after a bit of tinkering, this was quite a complex solution that didn't quite work for me. I had a number of groups nested inside the overall group and so their inner elements were all relatively positioned... I tried using `.getCTM()` and getting the translation, but after an hour or two of trial and error that wasn't working :\

Comment: The bounding box is relative to the local coordinates already. Even if you nest your group inside several groups with translations and scaling applied, the bounding box will still correctly bound your elements. See updated example [**HERE**](http://jsbin.com/pebix/2/edit?js,output). Perhaps I am misunderstanding your issue though. At any rate it seems you've found a solution that works for you, good luck.

Comment: I have found a solution, thanks again! For the sake of clarification though, what I meant was that my inner elements were nested within groups. Within the context of your example, the circles' parent would not be the same parent as the rect, as they would be nested within some other groups as well. Therefore, when calling `.getBBox()`, I get the x and y positions relative to the nested inner groups (instead of just relative to `theGroup` as in your example). 
Example: `<g><rect></rect><g transform='translate(50,50)'><g transform='translate(100,30)'><circle x='2' y='3'></circle></g></g></g>`